# How to full screen a textaera in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I want to build a web app in Ionic in this application there is a form in textaera

And as a notepad on IPhone I would like the textaera to be the size of the device used

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with CSS:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Here, you are setting the width of `textarea` to `100vw` (viewport width) & height to `100vh`(viewport height). This will make `textarea` adjust itself to the device width & height automatically.